# Checkbox: disable/enable href in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to enable/disable my `<a href>` button via a checkbox (default = disabled).  Is it possible?

```
$('#check').change(function() {

});
```

What is the next step? I think I need unbind function?

(I want to disable checkout button until user not clicking on Terms And Conditions checkbox).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable and enable a link, this should work:

```
$('.button').click(function(){ return false; }); // initially disabled.
$('#check').click(function() {
  if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
    $('.button').bind('click', function(){ return false; });
  }else{
    $('.button').unbind('click');
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hQJXW/3/

Comment: This is working inversely. If checkbox is selected, then it's unclickable and when is unselected, then it's clickable. :)

Comment: Interesting, because stops working after negotiating http://jsfiddle.net/hQJXW/2/

Comment: Really? It works fine here? Oh, the link is not disabled before the checkbox has been clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/hQJXW/3/

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQJXW/)

HTML:

```
<a id="to-toggle" data-href="http://google.com/">My Link</a><br />
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox"> Toggle it
```

JS:

```
var link = $("#to-toggle");
$("#toggle").on("change", function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        link.attr("href", link.data("href"));
    } else {
        link.removeAttr("href");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#check').mousedown(function(){
    if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.link').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: <a href> can have 'disabled' attribute?

Comment: Yes, I am looking solution for <a> tag, your solution works nicely with form elements only.

Comment: I made the same mistake and wrote something to disable a button and was about to post it when I saw this. I don't think you can disable an anchor tag, you may have to add div and change the z-index when the checkbox is clicked?